# laravel 9 scheduled job executed but not queued

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, laravel-9, laravel-jobs, laravel-scheduler

I recognised a strange behavior after upgrading laravel from 8 to 9. I have a scheduler that executes some jobs.

Kernel.php:

```php
$schedule->job(new ImportAzApplications, 'imports')
    ->everyFiveMinutes()
    ->onOneServer()
    ->onFailure(function () {
        Log::error('Scheduled "ImportAzApplications" failed');
    });
$schedule->job(new ImportServicePrincipals, 'imports')
    ->everyFiveMinutes()
    ->onOneServer()
    ->onFailure(function () {
        Log::error('Scheduled "ImportServicePrincipals" failed');
    });
```

The scheduler will be executed by an cron job in kubernetes. At the `artisan schedule:run` command will be executed every 5 seconds.

Logs:

```
[2022-04-23T10:55:06+00:00] Running scheduled command: App\Jobs\ImportServicePrincipals
[2022-04-23T10:55:06+00:00] Running scheduled command: App\Jobs\ImportAzApplications
```

Now I would except having two jobs in the `imports` queue. And I do. But only on my dev machine, not on the staging server.

One of the Jobs look like this:

```php
class ImportAzApplications implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $instance = new AzureApplications();
        $params = $instance->azApplicationImportParams();
        try {
            $instance->import($params);
            Log::debug('ImportAzApplications: Processing AzureApplications::importAzApplications');
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            Log::error('ImportAzApplications: '.$exception->getMessage(), $params);
        }
    }
}
```

- I enabled debug log-level to fetch debug logs
- I run unit tests successfully local
- I validated the scheduler workflow on the stating server with `artisan schedule:list',` artisan schedule:run', `artisan schedule:test` and `artisan queue:work --queue=imports'
- I monitored the database online via `tinker`: `DB::table('jobs')->get()` and `DB::table('failed_jobs')->get()`. Both remains empty
- I run the Jobs manually in tinker `(new ImportAzApplications)->handle()` successfully
- I executed a different job (export task) in the same queue successfully

I'm pretty sure it's a super simple thing that I can't see atm but for now I'm running out of ideas and hope someone has some further ideas

Many thanks

## Edited

during the weekend, some magic happened and the jobs where executed according to the new logs. I'm going to investigate the voodoo-magic further on kubernetes.

Comment: a bit of a wild guess: maybe kubernetes does some odd caching. No matter which system you use, you always have to restart the queue worker after you change php code, since it is a living process (it preserves the state of the php code until you restart it). However I cant see how that happened here since a CRON-job with `php artisan schedule:run` basically starts a fresh instance every time.

Comment: you're very close to it. I figured it out and I'm going to write the actual solution. many thanks for your idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to excuse myself to the community. The Problem was actually caused by an pipeline workflow.

I run `laravel` on `kubernetes`. There're multiple pod for different exercises available.

### `app`

the actual laraval application

### `queue`

the same container image with a slide different configuration to process the jobs in the queues using the `php artisan queue:work --queue=imports` command

### `jobs`

a kubernetes job that executes scheduled jobs using the `php artisan schedule:run` command defined in the `App\Console\Kernel` every minute

Once a new release will be pushed to the registry, a `kubectl set env` command sets the new build version which forces the `app` Pod to grab a new container image. This is defined the kubernetes strategy.

However the `queue` run with the old image. I've forced the `queue` to get latest image (no voodoo-magic) and the jobs where executed.

Thanks for all that who took there time to investigate and try to reproduce this beavure. That wasn't easy.

Cheers!